# gradle war does not want to compile my project

Tags: java, spring, jboss, gradle

I am trying to use gradle to compile a war file to deploy to a JBoss 7.1 AS, but it fails to compile (cannot find ServletContext)....

See below for the gradle.build.

**the error:**

/workspace/AgileRunner/src/main/java/com/agilerunner/web/config/AgileRunnerApplicationInitializer.java:20: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method addListener(org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener)
location: interface javax.servlet.ServletContext
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
                      ^
/workspace/AgileRunner/src/main/java/com/agilerunner/web/config/AgileRunnerApplicationInitializer.java:22: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method addServlet(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet)
location: interface javax.servlet.ServletContext
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
                                                               ^
2 errors
:compileJava FAILED

**gradle.build:**

```
apply plugin:'eclipse'
apply plugin:'war'
apply plugin:'cargo'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    def cargoVersion = '1+'

    cargo 'org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-uberjar:$cargoVersion',
      'org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-ant:$cargoVersion',
      'org.jboss.as:jboss-as-controller-client:7.1+'

    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2+',
                'org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:1+',
                'org.jboss.as:jboss-as-controller-client:7.1+'

    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4+',
        'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4+',
        'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:2+',
        'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:2+',
        'log4j:log4j:1+'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4+'
}

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }

        dependencies {
         classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-cargo-plugin:0+'
        }
}
cargo {
containerId = 'jboss71x'
port = 8080
remote {
    hostname = '127.0.0.1'
}
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Y.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change your servlet-api dependency

from: `'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2+'`

to: `'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'`

The `ServletContext` prior to JEE6 (Servlet spec 3.0) didn't have the API mechanism to register a listener.

Also, `'org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:1+'` should be `providedRuntime` (if any). It is probably the reason you didn't have an error in your IDE, but did have using gradle compile